# Which versions of Ubuntu, (not flavors) does steam work on normally?

Tags: steam

Title. Does any version work with steam without any crap? 16.04, 17.04, 16.10, each of them just make the steam icon bounce around on my dock for a bit then it just stops and the application doesn't open. Are there any versions without this problem? Does 14.04 work? Or maybe the 16.04 game pack? I know there's a fix but every time I try it it doesn't work at all, does nothing.

Comment: Considering we don't know why it isn't starting for you, it's hard to say. Steam works on most versions of Ubuntu. 14.04, 16.04, and 17.04 should all work. 16.10 is end of life now. Your Steam (library folder) installation could be corrupt. You may be using graphics drivers which Steam does not officially support.

Answer (score 0):

What you report is actually a common problem with steam in Ubuntu.

To solve it after you install steam, you must run it from the terminal using the following:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

instead of just steam. Normally you just need to run it like this the first time.

Yout might need to change `DISPLAY=:0` to 
`DISPLAY=:1`.